# tracking iframes on multiple URLs in google tag manager

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have a script I'm using to track a form in an iframe on a specific page in Google Tag Manager. My question is how do I modify it so I can track it across multiple pages? Do I need to duplicate the tag and trigger or do I need to modify the script?

```
<script>
try {
var postObject = JSON.stringify({
event: 'GAEvent',
eventCategory: 'Form',
eventAction: 'Form Submission',
eventLabel: 'Form'
});
parent.postMessage(postObject, 'https://www.example.com/page');
} catch(e) {
window.console && window.console.log(e);
}
</script>
```

[image: GTM Setup as follows:]

Comment: show your GTM setup.

Comment: @BNazaruk added a screen shot to the original comment. They have multiple iframed forms on different pages on the parent site. Currently I can only get it to work if I create a tag for each parent page

Comment: This tag only deploys a message. There should be another tag that uses this data and sends an event. With a trigger that is being translated from a message listener to something else. And that message listener has to be deployed too, in a separate tag. So you should find two more tags.

Comment: @BNazaruk thanks - so it all works, i have a listener setup in the parent frame, a trigger for a form submission which deploys the message. Events are being captured in GA. My main thing is that I want to make sure it fires on all forms but this script specifies just one specific URL - do you know how i modify it?

Comment: ah, I see. You just gave way too much context, I guess. try either replacing the URL with "*" or try getting it from the parent object.

Comment: @BNazaruk after some testing the it's actually firing across all forms but I have no idea how. Not entirely sure what that URL bit does? It's the result I want but some clarity would be good if you have any lol

Comment: The URL is the target origin. Basically, your main window's url. It compares it to the parent and if it's different, it's not supposed to fire. You can read more on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `window.postMessage()` is the URL of the parent. It's made to avoid firing the message for parents that shouldn't get the messages. If you want every parent to get the message regardless of the parent URL, the `"*"` would be the option to go with.

More information on postMessage is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Looks like it's not much related to GTM, but more to the mechanics of postMessage.